# Is PSU and GPU from iMac 2010 compatible with iMac 2011?

Tags: imac, hardware, power, gpu

I bought a 27" iMac 2011 model with no GPU and power supply unit from an auction where you can’t test anything. I would like to know if I can add GPU and power supply unit from my old 27" iMac 2010.

I noticed that the brand for display for both the models are similar as they both are manufactured by LG. The LVDS connector for both the displays are different. However the power supply cables that the LCD connects to the PSU unit is the same. So are they compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the power supply and the GPU are interchangeable

- The Power Supply (PN# [614-0446](http://radnex.us/2009-2011_imac-27_power-supply)) is compatible from model years 2009 through 2011.  [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/iMac-Intel-27-Inch-EMC-2309-2374-2390-or-2429-Power-Supply/IF174-000?o=1) confirms this (see compatible models)
- [You can upgrade the 2009 and 2010 iMac computers with the GPU from the 2011 model](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249479/119271). So, the GPUs are compatible.

As for the LVDS connector, you’re only looking at one end.  You just need to get the cable that goes from the GPU to your appropriate LCD display (you can remove it from the GPU)

Comment: I didnt quite get the GPU part you mentioned. The LVDS connector is on the logic board and the LVDS cable connect the LCD to logic board. Are you saying that GPU also has LVDS connector?